# combine two table with different content to make a table where each id has two rows in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

hope you can help me with this. so i have one table that contains value

| user_id | Monday. | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa11 | 100 | 164 | 284 |
| bb22. | 223 | 143 | 346 |

and another table that contains count

| user_id | Monday. | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa11 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| bb22 | 5 | 2 | 3 |

how can i combine both so it looks like this?

| user_id | type | Monday. | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa11 | value | 100 | 164 | 284 |
| aa11 | count | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| bb22. | value | 223 | 143 | 346 |
| bb22 | count | 5 | 2 | 3 |

is it even a good practice to pivot long like this or should i just pivot wide so there would be columns monday_value, monday_count, tuesday_value, tuesday_count, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Simple union? :

```
select * from (
  select user_id, 'value' as type,Monday.,Tuesday,Wednesday
  from table1 
  union all
  select user_id, 'count' as type,Monday.,Tuesday,Wednesday
  from table2 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple way as given in answer by @eshirvana.

Or as per your ask, if you want to do it horizontally you can do it following way:

```
WITH week_value AS
 (
 SELECT 1 as user, 100 as monday
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 as user, 200 as monday
),
week_count as (
 SELECT 1 as user, 10 as monday
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 as user, 2 as monday
)
select A.user, A.monday as monday_value, B.monday as monday_count
from week_value as A
FULL JOIN week_count as B on A.user = B.user
```